# I got below error while generating release build in react native android .file already exist

Tags: react-native

```
D:\ReactNative Workspace\awesome\android>gradlew clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
D:\ReactNative Workspace\awesome\android>gradlew assembleRelease

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, D:\ReactNative
info Writing sourcemap output to:, D:\ReactNative
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 1 asset files
error EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\ReactNative'. Run CLI with --verbos
e flag for more details.
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\ReactNative'

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 14s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed

D:\ReactNative Workspace\awesome\android>
```

Comment: Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63371787/13379286) as this is also a similar problem to yours

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue, It's actually not an error you just need to check the path of your "**Key Store Path**" If there is any space between your path the build fails, Try changing the path which is free from spaces, then build the project you should not see any errors now.

Comment: you are the bosss

Comment: ultimately  you are the boss Mr Boss