# Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 React native build problem

Tags: react-native, android-bundle

I am working on react native. When i try to create a build of android using

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

then getting an

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

But when i create a build using below command build succesfully build

```
gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

But build not run on mobile device as i am opening my app after install it just crashed.

Also when i try to create build on different System (8gm ram) with same code then it creates build with same command and the build will successfully created. Provide me a solution for this,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `cd android`

after that use this `./gradlew clean`

and for apk `./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

or use this for aab `./gradlew bundleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

Try these commands and please tell me if it works

Comment: Build successfully with this, but crashing when opening the app

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had to run `npm run android` once and then `./gradlew assembleRelease` worked

UPDATE: Run following command and see output log to find the bug

`npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I had to run the app form within Android Studio.
That gave me a clearer error message which allowed me to fix the issue.

The error in my case had to do with `entryFile: "index.android.js",` inside `app/build.gradle`.
I had to change it to `index.js` since that was the entry point in  my RN project.