# Could not be generated release apk for the react-native project

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting these errors

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
>   warning: the transform cache was reset.
>   Loading dependency graph, done.
>   info Writing bundle output to:, C:\KLS
>   info Writing sourcemap output to:, C:\KLS
>   error EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\KLS'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>   Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\KLS'
>
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 9s
42 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 40 up-to-date

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63371787/13379286) could be solution for your problem please check this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Run this command into the terminal into your project Dir. It will create the assets and adding the drawable files into the assets dir and then

```
clean Project & Rebuild
```

Now try to make the release build from android studio. 
May be you will get the duplicate resource error. In that case,

```
remove the drawables folder && raw folder in res dir
```

Hope it will work.