# BUILD FAILED REACT NATIVE (Not generating apk)

Tags: react-native, npm, apk, npx

I am getting an error while generating apk file: Error says: Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Amna'
error EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Amna'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'npx.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
  >   Can you please guide me through this error, and what might cause this error???

With this command gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets, it creates apk file but app crashes, I am unable to understand what is causing such issue.

Comment: I think your problem is same and solution would be also [same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63371787/13379286)

Comment: Am sorry for my previous answer. [Try this new one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450887/13379286) It works for me